# How to resize Highcharts chart on KendoUI/Angular Window resize

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, kendo-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JpcexrBxO8AudCMKWVFG?p=preview) there's a KendoWindow on AngularJS that contains a Highchart. If you resize the window, the chart doesn't resize to fit in. The Highchart element is jQuery wrapped in a directive.

This worked in pure Jquery by setting the Highchart container with the style  `height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute`. With Angular there are more divs between the KendoWindow and the container and that's probably the problem.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div kendo-window="win" style="width:600px;height:400px">
  <div dir-highcharts render="render"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.render = 0;

        $scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(event, widget){
          if (widget === $scope.win) {
              $scope.render++;  // add 1 to render the chart when the window is created
          }
      });

}


app.directive("dirHighcharts", function() {

    var directive = {};

    directive.replace = true;

    directive.restrict = 'AE';

    directive.scope = {
                     render: '='
                  };

    directive.template = '<div id="container" style="height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;"></div>';


    directive.link = function (scope, element, attrs) { 

            scope.$watch('render', function(newValue,oldValue) {
                if ( newValue != oldValue ) {
                    renderChart();
                }
             });


        var renderChart = function() {
            var settings = {             
                    chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'line'
                }
                ,xAxis: {
                  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                      'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
               },
              series: [{
                      name: 'Tokyo',
                      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
                  }, {
                      name: 'London',
                      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
               }]
            };

            scope.chart = new Highcharts.Chart(settings);

        };
    };

    return directive;

});
```

Comment: At the beginning remove duplicate of files ( highcharts.js and highcharts.src.js is the same, but one of them (first) is minified only). Secondly set a width of container in percents instaed of 600px.

Comment: Please see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9I5K8UwCfBBKpXVUsarE?p=preview), this is what happens when I change the width from 600px to 100%. Note that the directive has an inner div with style `height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute`

Comment: I found something interesting; open the link above in chrome, enlarge the window (the chart will _not_ expand to fit), then press F12 (developer tools) and the chart will expand. What I need to do is to redraw the same way the F12 does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, re-drawing the chart when the KendoWindow is resized.

```
    $scope.options = {
            resize: function() {
                $scope.render++;
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        };
```

[plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/L1nW3H1399j1MjelMPUA?p=preview)